# Robot.txt Rule for specific pages

Tags: google-search, google-crawlers

Google Search and Bing Search engine crawls our domain. We want to hide few pages from the public only with parameters. Is there any possible way.

Example

```
mydomain.com/products/phone.xhtml?xtoken=value
mydomain.com/products/electronics.xhtml?xtoken=value
```

We don't want to hide `mydomain.com/products/phone.xhtml` at the same time We don't want to show the `mydomain.com/products/phone.xhtml?xtoken=value` is restricted content.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very poor way to do it, as you'll just alert the public to those addresses by typing them in robots.txt. You're assuming all crawlers respect robots.txt. Except for that, what's wrong with your solution?